# Tableview causes app to crash when dragged to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When scrolling further than the last post/item in the tableview, the app crashes and I get error message: "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Like it's trying to find another post that isn't there, but i don't know why... Posts in the tableview appears just as they should.

I believe there is something wrong here:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexpath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexpath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexpath) as? PostCell{
        cell.configureCell(post: post)

        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }
}
```

(when I remove the else part, I get this error: "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' )

```
var posts = [Post]()
```

Configuring cell:

```
func configureCell(post: Post) {

    self.post = post



    if post.altA.isEmpty == false {
        altALabel.text = post.altA["text"] as? String
        if let votes = post.altA["votes"]{
            self.altAVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
        }
    } else {
        print("No data found in Alt A")
    }

    if post.altB.isEmpty == false {
        altBLabel.text = post.altB["text"] as? String
        if let votes = post.altB["votes"]{
            self.altBVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
        }
    } else {
        print("No data found in Alt B")
    }

    if post.altD.isEmpty == false {
        altDLabel.text = post.altD["text"] as? String
        if let votes = post.altD["votes"]{
            self.altDVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
        }
    } else {
        print("No data found in Alt D")
        altDView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        altDVotesView.removeFromSuperview()
        altDLabelView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    if post.altC.isEmpty == false {
        altCLabel.text = post.altC["text"] as? String
        if let votes = post.altC["votes"]{
            self.altCVotesLbl.text = "\(votes)"
        }
    } else {
        print("No data found in Alt C")
        self.altCView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.botBtnsStackView.removeFromSuperview()
    }



import Foundation
```

class Post {

```
private var _text: String!
private var _postKey: String!
private var _backgroundImg: Int!

private var _altA: Dictionary<String, Any>!
private var _altB: Dictionary<String, Any>!
private var _altC: Dictionary<String, Any>!
private var _altD: Dictionary<String, Any>!




//TEXT
var text: String {
    return _text
}

//BACKGROUND
var backgroundImg: Int{
    return _backgroundImg
}

//POSTKEY
var postKey: String{
    return _postKey
}


//ALTERNATIVES
var altA: Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return _altA
}

var altB: Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return _altB
}

var altC: Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return _altC
}

var altD: Dictionary<String, Any> {
    return _altD
}



init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    self._postKey = postKey

    if let text = postData["text"]{
        self._text = text as! String
    } else {
        self._text = ""
    }


     if let backgroundImg = postData["backgroundImg"]{
        self._backgroundImg = backgroundImg as! Int
    }



    if let altA = postData["altA"]{
        self._altA = altA as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    }

    if let altB = postData["altB"]{
        self._altB = altB as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    }


    if let altC = postData["altC"]{
        self._altC = altC as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    } else {
        let emptyDictionary = [String: Any]()
        self._altC = emptyDictionary
    }


    if let altD = postData["altD"]{
        self._altD = altD as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    } else {
        let emptyDictionary = [String: Any]()
        self._altD = emptyDictionary
    }
}
```

}

rest of the tableview code(nothing special about it):

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}
```

Comment: Point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: The `else` part is not needed. Either you have that cell and it's working (i.e. dequed) or there is a serious bug in your cell handling.

Comment: whene I remove the else part, I get this error: "Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell' "

Comment: I get the error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" at "cell.configureCell(post: post)"

Comment: Show the declaration for `posts` and for `configureCell`. And put all of this information in your question, not in comments.

Comment: I put it all in the description, thanks.

Comment: Most likely it is an error in your numberOfSectionsInTableView or numberOfRowsInSection tableView delegate methods - can you show these please.

Comment: added to explanation @LouisLeung

Comment: Ok that indeed looks fine... good to rule out since it only crashes when you reach the end of your tableView, right?

Comment: if the error is being called in the cell.configureCell where in that method is it being called. also this shouldn't be the case given how your code looks like but put a break point and confirm that cell and post both exist when you're making that call. (breakpoint, then type `po cell` and `po post` in the lldb debugger. Make sure none come up as nil

Comment: also, I would avoid removing views from superview. It could be a cell reuse issue. If you remove, say altCView in one cell, then try setting the text in the label it might crash if self.altCView is a weak reference (because it'll get deallocated)

Comment: TLDR. can you post you property declarations for altCView and whatever. (and `altDLabelView` a subview of `altDVotesView` or are they separate

Comment: @gadu removing the views was the problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool, I added an answer. Would appreciate if you accepted it as correct :) (click the check mark next to it)

Comment: This also means that the error did not happen on the line `cell.configureCell(post: post)`. It was happening on a different line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so the issue is that you are removing `self.altCView` and the other views from superview.

You have to remember that cells are reusable, so whenever they go away from screen they're "dequeued" and reused.

So if a cell is originally an altD cell, and you remove all the other superviews, but then it gets reused as an altC cell. trying to set the label will crash the app since removing from superview will deallocate it from memory (if you are using a weak reference which for some reason is default for IBOutlet's. Another tip, make all your IBOutlets strong I just think it's better)

Once views are removed from superview they're gone forever unless you re-add them so I would avoid doing that on code that runs multiple times like `cellForRowAtIndex`

Try setting them as hidden (or frame as `CGZero`) (but again, be wary of cell reuse. assume that the cells you get never have the right values so always set to unhidden if you're using them and always set to hidden if you're not using them. its a common mistake to forget to setHidden = false if you do need it. It might still be hidden from the previous time the cell was used)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it wasn't a good idea to remove the views from the superview. I replaced all the removeFromSuperview() methods by using isHidden = true, and it't now working.

for example: altDLabelView.removeFromSuperview() is now altDLabelView.isHidden = True

thanks for the help!